# getting mergJSON to work in the iOS simulator - Livecode

Tags: json, livecode

I'm trying to use [mergJSON](https://github.com/montegoulding/mergJSON) in a Livecode project, but am having some trouble getting it to work outside of the IDE. The steps I've taken so far are:

1. Download the git project
2. Build the Xcode Project and get the bundle
3. Follow the steps in [this](http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/4071/l/6347-how-to-install-3rd-party-externals-for-use-in-the-ide-and-standalone-builder) tutorial.

I added the external to the Runtime folder as well as the Externals folder, but still no joy.

I've tried building the project for iPad and the simulator

I'm using Livecode 5.5.4 commercial version

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried building the project for iPad and the simulator

This bit is the problem. I've only just worked out how to get externals that use the desktop sdk to work on mobile and (at least the way I've implemented) it requires some tweaks I've sent as pull requests to the livecode repo.

I'll try and upload some binaries for it today to mergExt.com... while I'm at it I'd better finally put a commercial license option out if you want to use it on iOS.

BTW you add mobile externals differently. They come as a lcext file which you add in the copy files section of the standalone build settings.

Comment: Ahh it all makes sense now! Thanks for the heads up on using lcext instead of the bundle